# How to execute automation script using WebDriverManager without connecting to the internet? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

When I am trying to run the automation script without connecting to the internet, the below exception will  be returned:

**System.Net.WebException: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com''**

Is there any way to execute the script without connecting to the internet (Offline), by using specific chrome version or the version cashed in the WebDriverManager?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w7QM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sacm3.png)

Comment: The ChromeDriver's ChromeNetworkConditions should have the IsOffline Property... https://www.fuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/3.9.1/lib/net45/WebDriver.dll/OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome/ChromeNetworkConditions

Comment: The IsOffline property is used, but the exception still returned from WebDriverManager

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com''

Comment: Can you access website offline and perform the steps ?

Comment: Yes, I have accessed this website without an internet connection
https://chris.bolin.co/offline/
but the WebDriverManager still returns the same exception.

Comment: are you trying to download the chrome web driver or using the local copy of exe?...  Edit the post to include your code and highlight the line of code where it throws error.

Comment: I am trying to download the chrome driver using WebDriverManager.
The question has been editied.
Please check the attached screenshots.

Comment: For another reasons I need to use the WebDriverManager
So, in case I need to access website offline using WebDriverManager, this thing not doable using WebDriverManager?

Comment: The WebDriverManager's sole purpose is to automate the process of downloading and referring the exe path/environment variable. It always checks for the latest version over the internet, downloads it and then uses that exe to instantiate. So you cannot use WebDriverManager in an offline mode.

Comment: Having said that you can create your own ChromeOfflineConfig which will inherit IdriverConfig

Comment: if you want to run the selenium tool in a server with no intermet access you can set up the proxy... new DriverManager().WithProxy(previouslyInitializedProxy).SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the chromedriver from:
https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Once you've downloaded the required files extract the zips to a local drive on your computer.

Make sure to add the path to where you extracting the chromedriver.exe

```
IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(@ "D:\Download\chromedriver"); //<-Add your path

driver.NetworkConditions = new ChromeNetworkConditions() {
  IsOffline = true, DownloadThroughput = 5000, UploadThroughput = 5000, Latency = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5)
};

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://chris.bolin.co/offline/");
```

> Note: You could also create an environment variable named
> webdriver.chrome.driver on your machine that's value is the path to
> where the local chromedriver.exe is located. If you set up a
> webdriver.chrome.driver variable you would not have to pass the chrome
> driver argument when you create a ChromeDriver instance